# Jquery / Javascript: Add and remove Class won't work on mobile devices

Tags: android, jquery, ios, css, mobile

i've wrote this code for my navigation. It counts the elements and check if you reached the area by scrolling down. Then it set the active class to the right entry in the navigation and removes the old active from the li.

So this works fine on desktop but not on mobile devices. I give the first element (Home) active. After scrolling to the next part, the active won't remove on the first li and it's not added to the new li.

**So here is my HTML Code:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" onclick='location.reload(true); return false;' target="_self"><img width="155px" height="auto" alt="Media Solutions GmbH" src="../misc/images/ms_logo.gif"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Digitalisierung</a></li>
        <li><a href="#usecase">Einsatzbereiche</a></li>
        <li><a href="#benefit">Ihr Nutzen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service">Unsere Leistungen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Weitere Informationen <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <?php include '../includes/naviInner.php'; ?>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

**and here my Jquery:**

```
//navigation
var navHeight = $('nav').height();
var scroll_pos = 0;

//NavBar
var aNavBar = $.map($(".marker"), function(n, i){
    return n.id;
});

//var aNavBar = ['home','about','prozess','vorteile','team','kontakt'];
var oNavBar = { 0: [0,0,1] };
// MenuName || Offset+NavHeight || Index || ChildIndex
for (i=1; i<aNavBar.length; i++) {
    var myOffset =$("#"+aNavBar[i]).offset().top;
    oNavBar[i] = [ myOffset, i, i+1 ];
}

$(document).scroll(function() {
    var curr_scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop() + 30;
    var bMatchFound = false;
    for (i=0; i<aNavBar.length-1; i++) {

        if ( oNavBar[i][0] <= curr_scroll_pos && curr_scroll_pos < oNavBar[i+1][0]) {
            myChildIndex = oNavBar[i][2];

            //Construct selector string
            mySelector = "nav .nav > li:nth-child(" + myChildIndex + ")";
            //Assign classes
            $("nav .nav > li").removeClass("active");
            $(mySelector).addClass("active");
            bMatchFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //We reached the last NavBar-Element
    if (!bMatchFound) {
        mySelector = "nav .nav > li:nth-child(" + oNavBar[aNavBar.length-1][2] + ")";
        $("nav .nav > li").removeClass("active");
        $(mySelector).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

It works great on desktop but it won't mark the active area in the navigation on mobile :( Please help! On mobile only "Home" will be set active beacause its hardcoded in the html. Looks like the JS takes no effects to the naviagtion.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `aNavBar` and `oNavBar` defined?

Comment: oh sorry there is a missing block of code -> edited my post. Thanks for the info